# What is the difference between an JSON and Array?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between an JSON and Array? Why do they call JSON Objects and Array Objects.

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Using+TableViews+-+data.js

Is this an Array or JSON? How can i identify?

Comment: wow.. that's like comparing a snail to a ferrari oO. Two totally different things. An array is n indexed data structure found in probably all langauges: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type
JSON on the other hand is a data exchange format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
Put this in a comment because it was too short for a real answer :)

Comment: A generalization of the question is: What is the difference between a data exchange format and a datatype? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON is a data format that is based on a subset of JavaScript.

A simplified version of the specification is available on the [JSON homepage](http://json.org/). The [full specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) is available as an IETF RFC.

Libraries exist in many different languages to convert from a string of JSON data into data structures appropriate for that language (and to go the other way). A list of some of them can be found near the bottom of the JSON homepage.

An array is a data structure common to most programming languages which contains a number of variables in a specific order. JSON has an array data type.

A JSON Object is a serialisation of a collection of key/value pairs. Most programming languages have a matching data structure, such as a hash in Perl or a (simple) object in JavaScript.

In the page you link to, there is no mention of JSON. It has a variable (`weatherData`) to which is assigned a simple object (using an object literal `{}`) which has one key (`reports`) to which is assigned an array (using an array literal `[]`) that contains a number of objects, each of which consists of a bunch of key/value pairs where the values are all strings.

If you were to remove the first line, and the semi-colon at the end, then the example would be a JSON data structure representing the same information. This is because, as I said earlier, JSON is based on a subset of JavaScript and that part of the example conforms to the subset.

Answer (score 0):

It's neither a JSON text ([JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a *text* data-interchange format - if it's not a `String`, it's not JSON) nor an `Array`.

It's an `Object`, defined as an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_Literals), with one property - `reports` - which is an `Array` (defined as an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Array_Literals)) of `Object` instances with properties describing weather conditions in cities.